# DNAT forwarding based on source

Tags: iptables, nat

I want to setup two IPSec tunnels using two different Google Cloud VPN gateways -- `GW_IP_1` and `GW_IP_2` -- with two behind-NAT routers -- `R1` and `R2`. Something like this:

```
GW_IP_1 ---\                                    /--- R1
            |-- my_main_router_NAT_firewall ---|
GW_IP_2 ---/                                    \--- R2
```

The problem: forward `UDP` port `500` to specific routers (`R1` and `R2`) based on source IP address of a gateway (`GW_IP_1` and `GW_IP_2`).

I ended up in a strange situation: one tunnel is up and packets are matching and are forwarded correctly, but packets **for the second router, R2** are not matching and it looks like they disappear somewhere.

On the main NATting router I created DNAT rules:

```
-t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -s GW_IP_1 --dport 500 -j DNAT --to R1:500
-t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -s GW_IP_2 --dport 500 -j DNAT --to R2:500
```

I run `tcpdump` on both `R1` and `R2`. `R1` got the packet and bring up the tunnel, **but the R2 does not see any packets to 500**. I then run `tcpdump` on the `main_router` too -- packets from both `GW_IP_1` and `GW_IP_2` are arriving as expected.

I spent several days fighting with the routers (Ubiquiti ER-X), etc. thinking that this is a firmware bug or something specific for this type of routers. But then I setup a simple Linux router from the start -- with two interfaces, forwarding and all rules and the result is the same -- one tunnel is up (packets are forwarded correctly) and the second router does not receive any packets.

So this is probably something more fundamental to `iptables`/kernel.
Could someone explain?

Comment: Does the packet count for your second rule increase from zero (i.e. is the rule seeing any packets)?

Comment: Is GW_IP_2 on same subnet as GW_IP_1?

Comment: @roaima no, that is one of the problems -- I see those packets using tcpdump but they do not match. I don't understand this.
#DDS these are different public addresses, they might be on a single subnet though as I think now. These are Google's IP's starting with 35.246 so the mask would be no less that 16.

Comment: So you have to tell the default gateway (if addresses are on different networks) to forward the packets directed to the second gateway to it.

Comment: @DDS You asked about GW_IP_1 and GW_IP_2 -- those are independent public IP's. As for R1 and R2 they are on the same network. The main_router in the middle is doing the DNATing.

Comment: I ran tcpdump on the main router: packets from `GW_IP_1` and `GW_IP_2` are arriving as expected. Then, the main router forwards only the packets from `GW_IP_1` but **not** from `GW_IP_2`

Comment: OK please add that to you question because it's not at all obvious you've done that.